# how to handle http errors in flask-classful?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am using flask_classful, no doubt its an amazing extension. now i want to handle http errors like 404, 500 etc. i don't know how to do that in flask-classful. Please Help me !

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_classful import FlaskView, route

app = Flask(__name__)


friends = ({'1st' : 'honey', '2nd' : 'ayush'})

class HomeView(FlaskView):
    route_base  = '/'

    def home(self):
        return render_template('global.html', title='Flask Claasful')

    @route('/new/')
    def new_func(self):
        return render_template('global.html', title='Flask Classy')

    @route('/friends/')
    def friends(self):
        return friends



HomeView.register(app)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: have you tried registering handlers as you would in Flask?

Comment: No. i am gonna try that.. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: i am kinda new to flask_classful, could you please show me how to do that ??

Comment: Did you find the answer for this? Internet doesn't have anything about this.

Answer (score 0):

```
class HomeView(FlaskView):
    route_base  = '/'

    def home(self):
        return render_template('global.html', title='Flask Claasful')

    @route('/new/')
    def new_func(self):
        return render_template('global.html', title='Flask Classy')

    @route('/friends/')
    def friends(self):
        return friends

    @app.errorhandler(404):
    def handleNotFound(self):
        print(self.name) # Not Found
        print(self.code) # 404
        print(self.description) # The requested URL was...
        print(self.get_headers()) # [('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')]
        response = self.get_response()
        print('Code:', response.status_code )
        print('Data:', response.data)
        return response
```

Try it with:

```
    $ echo "GET /fish\n\n" | openssl s_client -connect host.example.com:2222
```

self has namespace:
`'args', 'code', 'description', 'get_body', 'get_description', 'get_headers', 'get_response', 'name', 'response', 'with_traceback', 'wrap'`

unfortunately there is no get_request() method but it can be achived with by importing request from Flask itself and directly using it.

response object has namespace:

`'accept_ranges', 'access_control_allow_credentials', 'access_control_allow_headers', 'access_control_allow_methods', 'access_control_allow_origin', 'access_control_expose_headers', 'access_control_max_age', 'add_etag', 'age', 'allow', 'autocorrect_location_header', 'automatically_set_content_length', 'cache_control', 'calculate_content_length', 'call_on_close', 'charset', 'close', 'content_encoding', 'content_language', 'content_length', 'content_location', 'content_md5', 'content_range', 'content_security_policy', 'content_security_policy_report_only', 'content_type', 'cross_origin_embedder_policy', 'cross_origin_opener_policy', 'data', 'date', 'default_mimetype', 'default_status', 'delete_cookie', 'direct_passthrough', 'expires', 'force_type', 'freeze', 'from_app', 'get_app_iter', 'get_data', 'get_etag', 'get_json', 'get_wsgi_headers', 'get_wsgi_response', 'headers', 'implicit_sequence_conversion', 'is_json', 'is_sequence', 'is_streamed', 'iter_encoded', 'json', 'json_module', 'last_modified', 'location', 'make_conditional', 'make_sequence', 'max_cookie_size', 'mimetype', 'mimetype_params', 'response', 'retry_after', 'set_cookie', 'set_data', 'set_etag', 'status', 'status_code', 'stream', 'vary', 'www_authenticate'`